# ms sql 2012 case syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table `survey_status_history` which is having columns `caseId, strsurveystatus, dtcreated`.

I want to fetch record from table for all status but when `status = 'pending'`, for this case query should return record for last five days only.

Below is my query.

```
select *
from survey_status_history ssh
where nisactive = 1 
      and case when ssh.strsurveystatus = 'pending' 
               then ssh.dtcreated > DATEADD(DAY, 5 , GETDATE())
          end
```

But I am getting error near `>`

Kindly suggest the changes in query.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't understand a boolean type.  I would recommend writing this without the `case`:

```
select *
from survey_status_history ssh
where nisactive = 1 and
      (ssh.strsurveystatus <> 'pending' or
       ssh.dtcreated > DATEADD(DAY, 5 , GETDATE())
      );
```

This assumes that `strsurveystatus` is never `NULL`.  If it is `NULL` the logic is slightly more complicated.

Comment: thanks for prompt response.
my query should return all record in case of status is not pending but when status is pending then only i have to check whether that record is last 5 days record or not.

Comment: @MangeshKh - that appears to be what the query Gordon has supplied produces - if you think differently, can you provide an example of a row that should be returned that Gordon's query doesn't or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this suits your requirement.

```
SELECT *
FROM SURVEY_STATUS_HISTORY SSH
WHERE NISACTIVE = 1 AND
(SSH.STRSURVEYSTATUS <> 'PENDING' -- if not pending
 OR(SSH.STRSURVEYSTATUS = 'PENDING' AND SSH.DTCREATED >= DATEADD(DAY, -5 , GETDATE()))) -- if pending and last 5 days
```